# JRuby EventMachine no such file to load

Tags: jruby, eventmachine

I have intalled EventMachine in JRuby (I am using Win32). When I try the server example, I get an error when

```
require 'eventmachine'
```

The error is:

```
C:\dev\em>jruby server.rb
```

server.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- eventmachine (LoadError)
        from server.rb:1

But the gem is installed!

```
C:\dev\myapp>jruby -S gem install eventmachine
Successfully installed eventmachine-0.12.8-java
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for eventmachine-0.12.8-java...
Installing RDoc documentation for eventmachine-0.12.8-java...
Could not find main page README
Could not find main page README
Could not find main page README
Could not find main page README
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to first load RubyGems,

```
require 'rubygems'
```

Comment: Alternatively, adding the `-rubygems` argument on the command line will also work.

Answer (score 0):

The gem may not be installed for jruby. Try `jgem install eventmachine`